# Downloaded file is made of Content-type header instead of actual file content

Tags: php, http-headers, content-type

[NB. Major edit : same question, but with more info]

I'm trying to create a PHP script that

1. Generate an .xlsx file
2. Invite the user to download it.

Part 1 is OK (the generated file on the server is correct). Part 2 is not.

I have two files to do the job. The first one is XLSXExport.php, with the following code:

```
<?php
function exportDataToXLSX()
{
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/_inc/lib/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/_inc/lib/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");

   $outputFileName = 'query.xlsx'; //TODO hash pour le nom
   $outputFilePath = dirname(__FILE__).'/_store/'.$outputFileName;
   $outputFileType = 'Excel2007';

   //Creates a PHPExcel object
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

   //– Les Données
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
   $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, "Test");

   //– On sauvegarde notre fichier (Format Excel 2007)
   $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
   $objWriter->save($outputFilePath);

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($outputFilePath) . "\"");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($outputFilePath));
   header("Connection: close");

   @readfile($outputFilePath);
   exit();
}

exportDataToXLSX();
?>
```

The second file simply includes the first one:

```
<?php
   require_once('XLSXExport.php');
?>
```

When I launch the first file, everything goes well : I'm asked to save/open an xlsx file, which has the "Test" value in the right cell.

When I launch the second file, the file I'm asked to open/save is somehow a corrupted file which seems to be made of the HTML headers sent.

An example of output file (not the one precisely from this minimal example, but from the original file from which the minimal example has been made) is available here : https://mega.co.nz/#!HgpVDSAZ!tIYORzqX8GkFqiRQgWNTH_0J8zC0JyBfSLVejskqh-E

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: *All* of the headers or just some of them?

Comment: That I don't know. I've added to the question the link to the .csv file obtain saving the corrupted downloaded file.

Comment: I've edited the question with a minimal (not) working example.

Answer (score 1):

Last update:

I think I managed to reproduce your error. This is the error I'am getting

> Excel cannot open the file 'test.xlsx' because the file format or file
>   extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted
>   and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

and this is the content of the file; as you can see, just the same content you've got.

[image]

First, make two brand new files; the content for the first one copy from here http://ideone.com/GVVPVb while the content for the second file is here http://ideone.com/9rVueZ. Don't add any other lines at first. Run it, and everything should be fine.

In other words, somewhere you may have a whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>`, an UTF-8 Byte Order Mark, maybe a previous error, warning or a notice, a function like `print`, `print_r`, `echo`, `var_dump`, any raw `<html>` area before `<?php` code or anything that produces an output before `<?php` code.

---

[Previous Edits]

Try something like this (just tested)

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
header("Connection: close");

@readfile($filename); // or try echo $filename; 
exit();
```

One of following might be added as well, but it works even without them

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
```

You may add following ones to prevent loading from cashe (IE case)

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

EDIT:

Since your output is actually a CSV file you can build it using `fputcsv()` like this

```
build_csv(array(
    array("data 1", "data 2", "data 3", "data 4"),
    array("data 2", "data 2", "data 2", "data 4")
));

function build_csv($buffer) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($buffer as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

Comment: Same problem for me with any combination or these groups of header.

Comment: @Silverspur This is something I'd done hundreds of times; however, I updated the answer so give it a try.

Comment: I did not say your code was wrong, I just observed it does not work when I test it in my context. The error is certainly somewhere else, hidden in something I did not mention because thought it was irrelevant.
And no, what I generate (and expect to download) is indeed a xlsx file ; I have posted the .csv because it is the default format LibreOffice suggests when saving the corrupted file.
Anyway, thanks for the update.

Comment: @Silverspur Since you unaccepted the answer I guess you're still struggling with this issue, right? :)

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with a minimal example.
It seems the issue comes from the fact that the generation+header code is included from another php file.

Comment: @Silverspur I see. According to this _When I launch the first file, everything goes well ..._ your code (the first file) doesn't work if you call it from the second file with `require_once('XLSXExport.php')` ; otherwise it works fine; am I right?

Comment: @Silverspur Check the last update; I think I've found what's causing of the issue.

Comment: It was indeed a hidden UTF8 BOM. I thought I had removed it succesfully because even VIM did not diplay it anymore, but apparently it was still there :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may occurs because apache/php send "somethings" to browser before your header.
Do you have any empty characters in your second file before/after php tag ?

You should have a look to your error_log, to check if php complaint about being unable to send header.

Also, if output_buffering is on, try to put it off (if on, php won't complaint about output before header, but "empty" characters will be send just after the header, leading to corruption in case of a file download)

Comment: Disabling the output_buffering was indeed a good idea, since I did not see error messages when it was on.
I'll vote for your answer as soon as I have regained enough reputation :)